# common component across all CQ5 pages

Tags: aem

I have created menu component, through which authors enter name, url field values.The component script renders the menu based on name, url entries.

**Question : how to make this menu component common across all CQ5 pages, so it is not drag and dropped on each page.**

Thank you,
Sri

Comment: why not put that code (to include the common component) into your page component?

Comment: If you want to have it configurable on one page and reuse it everywhere one option would be iparsys, which is an inheriting parsys that traverses up the page hierarchy until it finds a component in it.

Comment: @awadheshv It will create content on specific page where the menu entries entered and the content created will not be available to other pages. This is not a regular navigation using site/page tree, rather author enter name of page, path of page.

Comment: Use iparsys. One more solution could be to design your common component to fetch properties from the predetermined page, say language page, and use them (instead of current component properties).

Answer (score 2):

ACS AEM Commons now supports this functionality without use of an iparsys - Shared Component Properties (http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/shared-component-properties.html)

Configure your menu with Shared and/or Global properties and you can simply template it directly onto all of your pages (no iparsys required).  You can then edit the menu from any page on the site and it will by updated on all pages.